# Group 13 elements reactivity with halogens

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

All the trihalides of the Group 13 elements are known, but $\ce{TlI3}$ is not. Why is this so?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thallium_triiodide answers it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the Inert Pair Effect. As we move down the 13th group, addition of d orbitals and f orbitals are taking place. Since the d orbitals and f orbitals are away from the nucleus, they have poor sheilding power or capability and thus the s orbitals of the outermost shell are attracted towards the nucleai, making it difficult for s orbital electrons to leave the orbitals and only pairing of the 1 electron in p orbital is possible. Thus +1 valency of Tl is more stable than +3 as it is not energetically favored. This,ofcourse, does not mean that formation TlI3 is not possible. It's just that it requires more energy.

Comment: There's also relativistic effects.

Comment: You should also explain why only iodide is unable to bring out the +3 oxidation state.

Comment: @orthocresol Isnt that due to size of iodine?

Comment: Indirectly, yes, but just saying that doesn't explain anything